# php eval string as function

Tags: php, eval

What is the best way to go about defining a php function and the call to that function, in a string, and then executing that code i.e., eval? I'm trying to get the length of an encoded uri out of a function defined and called in a string.

```
$json_arr['my_function'] = "function hashfun1($enc_uri) { return strlen($enc_uri); } hashfun1($enc_uri);";
$hash_func = $json_arr['my_function'];
$hash_val = eval($hash_func);
print_r($hash_val); // should be length of encoded uri but displays "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE"
exit;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with that code. Why do you need `eval()` in the first place?

Comment: No parse error here.  Lots of other errors.

Comment: Why, in first place, you're doing it using `eval`?

Comment: Why is your function stored in a string?  Where is that string coming from?  Remember, "if `eval()` is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question".

Comment: What is `$enc_uri`?  Where is it coming from?

Comment: The function is being returned as a json response from a rest service. I need to use the function returned to get the length of an encoded uri: `function encodeURIComponent($str) {
    $revert = array('%21'=>'!', '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')');
    return strtr(rawurlencode($str), $revert);
}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want:

```
$json_arr['my_function'] = "function hashfun1($enc_uri) { return strlen($enc_uri); } hashfun1('" . $enc_uri . '");";
```

You missed to populate `$enc_uri`.

Don't do this in production code, although it works. [`eval()` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php). You have been warned.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape "$" in double-quoted string. And check number of returns (second for eval):

```
$json_arr['my_function'] = "function hashfun1(\$enc_uri) { return strlen(\$enc_uri); } return hashfun1(\$enc_uri);";
```

Comment: and why you use eval? It breaks opcode cache and makes sense in rare cases. If you look for dynamic function generation, check this:
(old)
http://php.net/create_function
http://php.net/call_user_func_array
(new)
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess I need to use call_user_func(); This worked for me: `$json_arr['my_function'] = function($enc_uri) { return strlen($enc_uri); };
$hash_val = call_user_func($json_arr['my_function'], $enc_uri);
print_r($hash_val);
exit;`

Thanks for the help guys.